# mutate on grouped database column using 'first()' without collect()'ing first

Tags: sqlite, dplyr, dbplyr

Without using the `collect()' function I'm getting an error with my code

```
joined_table %>%
  filter(message.y == 'CURR') %>%
  filter(parameter.y == 'Volt') %>%
  select(flight, timestamp.y, value) %>%
  #collect() %>%
  group_by(flight) %>%
  mutate(first = first(timestamp.y)) %>%
  mutate(shifted = (timestamp.y - first)/ 60)
```

Error:

```
Error: Window function `first_value()` is not supported by this database
```

I wish to take the timestamp column and shift it to begin from zero for each flight for ploting. If I add in the commented `collect()` the function works as it imports the data into R. This is very early in the pipline and has a serious overhead for me as the database is 80Gb.

What alternatives do i have?

1. Can I use some other functions to achieve the same result as I get from those 2 mutates? (Maybe something from zoo?)
2. Should I move from SQLite to some other database that supports `first_value()`?
3. ??

Comment: You can still group and join back on the original.

Answer (score 0):

RTFM

SQLite does not support window functions and as there is quite abit of data, migration is in order.